# How do I interact with a DomDocumentFragment

Tags: php, dom, phpgt, phpgt-dom

I was expecting a DomDocumentFragment to behave as if it were a fragment of a DomDocument - but that isn't the case.  For example it doesn't have the basic PHPGT querySelector methos.

How do I manipulate the contents of the fragment, without putting it into the parent HTMLDocument and querySelecting it back out again?

The code:

```
$domDoc = new \phpgt\dom\HTMLDocument("<div>previously</div>");

$frag = $domDoc->createDocumentFragment();
$frag->appendXML("<div><span>hello</span></div>");
$frag->querySelector("span")->textContent = "goodbye";
```

produces the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method phpgt\dom\DocumentFragment::querySelector()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), the querySelector* methods should be available on a DocumentFragment so I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/PhpGt/Dom/issues/59) on github and am closing the question.